# How to handle files on Android with a QFileDialog?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt6

I'm making an app that selects a file and sends it over to a local server using Qt 6.5, it works as expected on desktop, but i noticed that the android version wasn't communicating any data, and after debugging the issue i think it has to do with the path to the image that i recieve from QFile Dialog

I had to use a QLabel to get the debug data out of my phone, but this is the path that i got from selecting an image,

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A5730

And after testing, i found that the path changes if i leave the 'Recent' tab, and navigate to the path to the image and select it that way, in that case the path i get is:

content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/76BC-663E%3ADCIM%2FCamera%2FIMG__20221107_192453.jpg

So my question is, how do i get the actual path to the image that i selected on the 'Recent' tab? Or if that's not possible, how do i get the extension from the first path?

Comment: Those are not paths but content schemes. They are different as they come from different content providers. You can query those uris using a content resolver for a .DISPLAY_NAME. If you have the name you have the extention too.